# MediaCodec gives IllegalStateException at getInputbuffer(index) in callback of OnInputBufferAvailable

Tags: android, mp3, android-mediacodec, decoder

I am decoding an mp3 file, first I convert the mp3 file into a chunks of **byteArray** of size 1000 and put it in a **circularArray** and then pass it to **mediaCodec callback** for decoding (decode one byteArray at a time), I follow this **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602108/mediacodec-decode-aac-audio-chunks-from-rtsp-and-play)**. **It is working fine for Samsung devices**, but if I use other than Samsung devices (Vivo, pixel 3a) **it crashes** at the **mediaCodec.getInputBuffer(index) in the callback of onInputBufferAvailable** by giving the exception **IllegalStateException**. My code is as follows:

```
var decoder: MediaCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("audio/mpeg")
decoder.configure(format, null, null, 0)
decoder.setCallback(object : MediaCodec.Callback() {
        override fun onInputBufferAvailable(mediaCodec: MediaCodec, i: Int) {

            while (true) {
                if (circularArray!!.size() > 0) {
                    val data: ByteArray = circularArray.popFirst()
                    val info = MediaCodec.BufferInfo()
                    val buffer = mediaCodec.getInputBuffer(i)
                    buffer!!.put(data, 0, data.size)
                    mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(i, 0, data.size, 0, 0)
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onOutputBufferAvailable(mediaCodec: MediaCodec, i: Int, info: MediaCodec.BufferInfo) {
            //DECODING PACKET ENDED
            val outBuffer = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffer(i)
            val chunk = ByteArray(info.size)
            outBuffer!![chunk] // Read the buffer all at once
            outBuffer!!.clear()
            Log.d(TAG, "onOutputBufferAvailable: ${info.size}")
            audioTrack!!.write(chunk, info.offset, info.offset + info.size) 
            mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(i, false)
        }

        override fun onError(mediaCodec: MediaCodec, e: MediaCodec.CodecException) {}
        override fun onOutputFormatChanged(mediaCodec: MediaCodec, mediaFormat: MediaFormat) {}
    })

    decoder!!.start()
```

**I converted my file like this**

```
val tempBuf = ByteArray(1000)
var byteRead: Int
    try {

        val bufferedInputStream = BufferedInputStream(FileInputStream(mp3File))
        while (bufferedInputStream.read(tempBuf).also { byteRead = it } != -1) {
            circularArray.addLast(tempBuf.copyOf())
        }
        bufferedInputStream.close()
        Thread(aacDecoderAndPlayRunnable).start()

    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        Log.d(TAG, "fileToInputStream: ${e.message}")
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
```

**The exception where the app crashes is**

[image: Crash]

Even if I try to get the format form **mediaCodec** in the callback, it gives an exception and crashes anyway. I also checked supportedTypes from the codec it supports audio/mpeg.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `MediaCodec` works with a queue of input buffers. And you can read more about it in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec).

The second parameter of the `onInputBufferAvailable` callback is the index of the buffer. When calling `getInputBuffer()` you must pass this index instead of 0:

> val buffer = mediaCodec.getInputBuffer(i)

Second, consider using the [`MediaExtractor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor) instead of reading the file yourself. It supplies you will presentation timestamps and flags to pass into `queueInputBuffer()`.

Third, you need to remove the `while (true)` loop. You can only queue one buffer per callback.

Comment: I wrote 0 instead of index mistakenly while copy pasting on stack overflow, although I am using index instead of 0. I also tried MediaExtractor but the result is same, I had the same exception (works on Samsung Device with MediaExtractor) . And also keep in consideration my code is working fine when I use Samsung devices. If I use other devices like Xiaomi, Pixel or Vivo I am having an exception by using mediaCodec which I get in the callback, even if I try to get anything form this mediaCodec like mediaCodec.codecInfo I get the exception.

Comment: OK, you also need to remove the `while (true)` loop. You can only queue one buffer at at time.

Comment: Additionally, you must pass the presentation timestamp of each buffer to `queueInputBuffer()`. You can get it from `MediaExtractor`.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/taehwandev/MediaCodecExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/tech/thdev/mediacodecexample/audio/AACAudioDecoderThread.kt)

Comment: The linked example uses the `MediaCodec` in the synchronous mode. This is the old and less convenient way. While you have callbacks and you can only process one buffer in your callback.

Comment: I also tried this [example](https://github.com/taehwandev/MediaCodecExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/tech/thdev/mediacodecexample/audio/AACAudioDecoderThread.kt), but instead of aac file I used **mp3 file** and also I changed my decoder to **audio/mpeg**. And in this example he uses mediaExtractor. Regardless of any change, it is working on Samsung device and not working on any other device. I also tested this on OlePlus 8t but result is the same it crashes at line 128 by calling _decoder.outputBuffers_ with same exception **IllegalStateException**.

Comment: But did you remove the `while (true)` loop and are you sending the timestamps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250280/discussion-between-shan-ahmad-and-dev-bmax).